# Why does Formik never recognize my Ionic IonInput values?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, formik, yup

I'm using Ionic 7, React 18, and Formik 2.4.5.  Does Ionic work with Formik?  I tried creating a very simple form with just a first and last name ...

```
const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({  }) => {



  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    firstName: Yup.string().required('First Name is required'),
    lastName: Yup.string().required('Last Name is required')
    // Add other fields to validate here
  })

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null
      }}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
      }}
    >
      {(formikProps) => (
        <>
          <strong>Sender Information</strong>

          <form onSubmit={formikProps.handleSubmit}>
            <IonInput placeholder='First Name' value={formikProps.values.firstName} onIonChange={formikProps.handleChange} />
            {formikProps.touched.firstName && formikProps.errors.firstName ? <div>{formikProps.errors.firstName}</div> : null}
            <IonInput placeholder='Last Name' value={formikProps.values.lastName} onIonChange={formikProps.handleChange} />
            {formikProps.touched.lastName && formikProps.errors.lastName ? <div>{formikProps.errors.lastName}</div> : null}

            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
          </form>
        </>
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

However clicking "Submit" always results in the error messages displaying even if I have typed text into them . When I remove the "validationSchema" property, I see my submit handler called, however, the values for the two fields are always empty even if I have entered text into them.  Curious if Formik is something that is meant to work with React at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Formik can be used with React and Ionic to manage and validate form state. The issue you're facing as per the code is related to the way the `onIonChange` event is handled for the `IonInput` component. The event object provided by `onIonChange` is different from the standard React `onChange` event. As a result, Formik is unable to capture the changes correctly, leading to errors in displaying validation messages and submitting the form.

Now, to fix the issue, the `onIonChange` event handler should use Formik's ***[`setFieldValue`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--promisevoid--formikerrors)*** function, which manually updates the field values when the event is triggered. Additionally, I added the name attribute to the `IonInput` components.

```js
<IonInput
  name='firstName'
  placeholder='First Name'
  value={formikProps.values.firstName}
  onIonChange={(e) => formikProps.setFieldValue('firstName', e.detail.value)}
/>
{formikProps.touched.firstName && formikProps.errors.firstName ? (
  <div>{formikProps.errors.firstName}</div>
) : null}
<IonInput
  name='lastName'
  placeholder='Last Name'
  value={formikProps.values.lastName}
  onIonChange={(e) => formikProps.setFieldValue('lastName', e.detail.value)}
/>
{formikProps.touched.lastName && formikProps.errors.lastName ? (
  <div>{formikProps.errors.lastName}</div>
) : null}
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/winter-pine-d8xn95?file=%2Fsrc%2FMyComponent.tsx%3A24%2C6)***

**Suggestion:**

You should consider looking at [*React-hook-forms*](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--promisevoid--formikerrors) library as well. It is lightweight, and compatible with Ionic, React.

**References:**

1. [Comparison of Formik and React-hook-forms](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2023/02/comparing-react-form-libraries/)
2. [Github issue](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1981)

Comment: I started with React hook forms, but ran into some issues -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77484203/in-ionic-react-how-do-i-display-an-error-message-when-my-form-is-submitted-but, at which point someone suggested I use formik.

Comment: @Dave oh ok. I will take a look at the question and try to answer it in some time.